# Overflow scroll while positioning at bottom

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I want my content to start at the bottom of its parent and extend upwards, allowing scrolling. The only way I could find to anchor to bottom is to use position relative/absolute in the parent/child, but it seems when I do this, along with absolute positioning the child at the bottom of its parent, overflow doesn't work correctly.

```
<div id="relative">
  <div id="inner">
    <div>
      scroll<br>
      stuff<br>
      here<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
#relative {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
```

}

I have more stuff to display in my inner div, so it definitely expands to a greater height than the outer div. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work when I position at the bottom? Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/ty1Lwyua/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that do it only with CSS is not a good idea. CSS is the document style sheet and you require something more "dynamic" (javascript to the rescue).

The CSS only solution can be more like a hack: http://jsfiddle.net/UDuqe/

The solution instead will be:

```
scrollToBottom = function () {
  var relative = document.getElementById("relative");
  relative.scrollTop = relative.scrollHeight;
};

scrollToBottom();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dcLcxpqj/1/

### Update:

To set the scroll on new inner div:

Add the html:

```
<form>   
    <input id="message" type="text">   
    <button onclick="addComment(event)"> Insert new Comment</button> 
</form>
```

Then add javascript:

```
addComment = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent the form submit (default behavior of "button")
    var relative = document.getElementById("relative");
    var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = message.value;
    relative.appendChild(div);
    message.value = "";
    scrollToBottom();
}
```

Whole solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e86pawn5/

Comment: Thank you, this answers my original question. The thing is, I dynamically insert content, and I want to start inserting it at the bottom of the relative container. It works if I position the inner container (where I insert the content) at the bottom and allow it to grow upwards, but could you show how to do this with your solution?

Comment: I updated the answer. When you add content to the inner div, simply call the scroll function and the work is done.